# ACE editor suggest on click

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have this instance of ACE running on my application. When a user writes a typo, I highlight it and, when he clicks on it I want to suggest some replacements. It's not an auto-suggest "as you type" because I don't want to be annoying.

The users are not technical and I don't want to push keyboard shortcuts onto them. Something simple like `onMouseEnter` or `onClick` would be perfect.

Consider this source: http://plnkr.co/edit/kalbc9fgMyPEZbVja8Yt?p=preview

How would you show the suggestions when the user hovers/clicks on the highlighted word?